# How to transfer data through NFC in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I want to upload the data from a electronic card which is NFC enabled to my NFC enabled device.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Android provides a [NFC Demo Code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html) , you should also read the [Android NFC topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html) .